# Backtick randomly appearing

Tags: keyboard, language

My Macbook Air (2014 Sierra) has suddenly started entering a backtick in the middle of words today. Mostly with the word **can** (appears as **ca`n**), with have, make, changing, change all display the same behaviour.

My keyboard is British UK, I have not changed any language settings. The behaviour is the same in every app and in every user account and in safe mode. It happens when using the Mac keyboard and external keyboard. I have searched all settings to find out what could have happened. I have reset the PRAM and SMC and aside from throwing it through the window I'm out of ideas!

The only change to my laptop in the last two weeks is installing Microsoft Teams and Citrix Receiver which I'm using to work for a client on.

If you need any more info from me to help identify my problem then let me know. I'm getting around it with autocorrect in Word but that doesn't help every other app! I'm keeping my fingers crossed that you brainy bunch ca`n help with a solution.

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem may be purely physical. It you have a source of dry compressed air, give the keyboard a good blow-out - there maybe something stuck in the key-switch making the connection. If you are in the habit of eating whilst using your laptop, it may be a tiny crumb of something you could pulverize to dust with a little staccato trilling on the ` key itself for 10 seconds. Its worked for me a few times.

Comment: Many thanks @IconDaemon. I did actually clean the keyboard last week - but it happens on the macbook keyboard (spotless) as well as my usual bluetooth keyboard. I've pulled the keys off and all is clean. The problem seems to be with the letter a following a consonant. It isn't happening with i's or e's or o's or u's - just a's.  Yes I know how stupid that sounds! LOL! But I just typed availa`ble into a document and you can see what I got in return!

Comment: Famous last words!!! I also just typed management and I got the ` at the end of manage so it isn't just the letter a that is the problem! A`nd even the letter a on its own isn't immune ... so there is a pattern of being linked to vowels but at the same time being random.

Comment: Can you remove Citrix, or try when logged into another account, and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem persists.  If it does - you've narrowed it down to either hardware or macOS itself and not anything 3rd party you've installed.

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke and Allan. I will try and remove Citrix (although it's been installed for two weeks and it's only just presenting this problem) - but I will give it a go and post back. I've tried Safe mode - the problem persists in every user account, and in safe mode. Any ideas of what could have changed in the macOS to corrupt it or maybe something I can repair? I've tried going through recently changed system files but am none the wiser.

Comment: You say it happens on two keyboards. Are they both UK ISO. I'm slightly concerned at the proximity of the ` key to the a key & wondering if something on one keyboard has a dodgy connection [the circuit tracks connecting keys are in inter-joined patterns, not that I know precisely what those patterns are] I'd try physically [or bluetooth-ly] disconnecting each & test the other in solo.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Yes both UK keyboards and disconnected bluetooth one and it still happened on the internal keyboard. But it seems that Citrix Receiver may be the issue. No idea how, but having disconnected from that and found that the issue is dormant. I'll update tomorrow when I'm working with the Citrix connection opened again to see if the problem persists therein. The problem appeared when working in the Citrix server and on the mac with the Citrix server connection live. If only people would leave me alone with my Mac without making me join in their hideous systems! :)

Comment: Update for info - after logging out of Citrix Monday evening the problem disappeared. I logged in periodically throughout the day Tuesday and the problem did not reappear. I also used Teams with no issue. It is potentially a total coincidence and nothing to do with the problem whatsoever, but I thought I'd post the update anyway. I do hate it when there is no obvious cause for an issue, but as long as it stays away I can type a document without it looking like a foreign language! Thanks for all the advice.